# AWS Cognito - PostSignUp Trigger Not Working

Tags: amazon-web-services, triggers, amazon-cognito

i have a post signup trigger setup to store the user details in DynamoDb table. This works fine when the user signs up on their own through the front-end but the trigger is never invoked if the user is created through AdminCreateUser API. Our assumption was after the newly added user gets an email with a temporary password and logins through the front-end, Cognito will invoke the postsignup trigger.

Is that an expected behavior? And also, how do we address this issue?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Although that's counter intuitive, seems that's the expected behavior.

`Post Confirmation` trigger is not invoked when a user is created via `AdminCreateUser` API.

Workaround could be to to use `Post Authentication` trigger and during processing of the fired event to check if `cognito:user_status` is `FORCE_CHANGE_PASSWORD`.

When a user is created using `AdminCreateUser`, status of the new user is set to `FORCE_CHANGE_PASSWORD`. Once user logs in and changes temporary password, status is changed to `CONFIRMED`.

Downside is that trigger is invoked after every login.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing. Thanks for your response, AWS should address this issue.

Comment: @Emon: AWS already knows about this since 2017: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=775800. Unfortunately they didn't resolve this issue still

Comment: For the record, I just ran into this issue.  It's 2023.  I'll now work on implementing the `Post Authentication` workaround as suggested above.

Comment: `Downside is that trigger is invoked after every login`. So, that sounds like a terrible tradeoff!

Comment: AWS needs to fix this.